# Creating multiple Excel chart objects using c#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I've spent hours now trying to create a few charts in Excel from my C# application. I'm trying to create more than one chart object. Is there a better way of doing this? I'm sure the line "chartObject[col] = (Excel.Chart)oWB.Charts.Add(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);" is where I'm going wrong.

At the moment, when I call this line, it sometimes creates a a copy of the last chart, but sometimes it works. I can't understand the logic to it at all.

Thanks

```
private void CreateCharts(Excel.Worksheet oWS, int numRows, int numCols)
    {
        Excel.Workbook oWB = (Excel.Workbook)oWS.Parent;
        Excel.Series oSeries;
        //Excel._Chart chartObject;
        Excel.Chart[] chartObject = new Excel.Chart[numCols];
        Excel.SeriesCollection[] oSeriesCollection = new Excel.SeriesCollection[numCols];
        int length = numRows + 2;
        string colname;

        //then you can assign as much as series you want,
        for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++)
        {
            //create a new chart
            chartObject[col] = (Excel.Chart)oWB.Charts.Add(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            chartObject[col].ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
            oSeriesCollection[col] = (Excel.SeriesCollection)chartObject[col].SeriesCollection();

            //add the actual occupancy
            colname = GetExcelColumnName(col * 3 + 1);
            oSeries = oSeriesCollection[col].NewSeries();
            oSeries.Values = oWS.Range[colname + "2", colname + length];

            //add the expected occupancy
            colname = GetExcelColumnName(col * 3 + 2);
            oSeries = oSeriesCollection[col].NewSeries();
            oSeries.Values = oWS.Range[colname + "2", colname + length];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm wondering if using ASP.NET's chart control will help you.  Or do you need to put this into Excel?  The chart control can put the chart right in the web page.  I set this up about a year ago, so if you have questions, let me know.  http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart  Another alternative would be to use the Sencha extjs framework for charting (http://www.sencha.com).

Comment: I can probably answer your question if you tell me what library you're using for Excel.  Also, if you can provide the code where you retrieve the workbook and worksheet (based on your first parameter in your method), that would also help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem my be that the *Chart* object in Excel is really a chart sheet, while a chart itself is a *ChartObject* object, and you use the *Shape* object it's in to handle it.  Here's [a link](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/QuickChartVBA.html), and [another one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa203725%28office.11%29.aspx) that talke about it a abit, and some VBA code from [this MS link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officedevdocs/archive/2008/10/30/office-chart-object-model-in-powerpoint-and-word.aspx) that shows a little of it, note that there are a few different ways to get it done:

```
Sub AddChart_Excel()   
  Dim objShape As Shape   

  ' Create a chart and return a Shape object reference.   
  ' The Shape object reference contains the chart.   
  Set objShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(XlChartType.xlColumnStacked100)   

  ' Ensure the Shape object contains a chart. If so,   
  ' set the source data for the chart to the range A1:C3.  
  If objShape.HasChart Then  
    objShape.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet1'!$A$1:$C$3")  
  End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I worked it out in the end using some of the info in your links.

Comment: Actually, a *Chart* is either a chart that is shown on a chart sheet (and the chart sheet is the *Chart* object) or it is a chart that is embedded in another sheet within a *ChartObject*, which is a special kind of *Shape*. In your code sample, if you'd declared your objShape as a ChartObject, you would not have had to check whether it contained a chart.

Comment: @Jon, I agree, I usually use the ChartObject directly also.  I'll see if I can come up with a better code sample sometime.

Comment: Lance - shoot me an email (jon at peltiertech dot com) and I'll send a few simple snippets of chart related vba.