# C# generate multiple charts in excel

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I want to generate two charts in excel. this is my code for generating the first one, then i want to generate one more in the same document using another range.

```
Range chartRange;
ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartRange = ws.get_Range("A4", "AZ4");
chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;
chartPage.HasTitle = true;
chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "Lägenhetstyp 1";
chartPage.HasLegend = false;
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
```

Something like this.

```
Range chartRange;
//First Chart
ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartRange = ws.get_Range("A4", "AZ4");
chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;
chartPage.HasTitle = true;
chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "Chart 1";
chartPage.HasLegend = false;
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
//Second chart
ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartRange = ws.get_Range("A8", "AZ8");
chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;
chartPage.HasTitle = true;
chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "Chart 2";
chartPage.HasLegend = false;
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968630/creating-multiple-excel-chart-objects-using-c-sharp

Comment: What is your actual question? You've stated what you've done, but what isn't working? or what do you need thats different that you need help with?

Comment: Problem solved. See below for solution. Thank you for answering my question :)

Comment: anyone now how i position my two graphs now they end up ontop of eachother

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved it.

```
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            Range chartRange;

            ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
            Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
            if (i == 1)
            {
                chartRange = ws.get_Range("A4", "AZ4");
            }
            else
            {
                chartRange = ws.get_Range("A8", "AZ8");
            }
            chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;
            chartPage.HasTitle = true;
            chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "Chart " + i;
            chartPage.HasLegend = false;
            chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
            chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
        }
```